# Store a box or dropbox file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, dropbox-api, box-api

I am writing an app engine app which has access both to box and dropbox api. 
I want to save the file into the google cloud storage.  Both of them have the FileOutPutStream as the output stream for the file to download. 
DropBoxAPI :

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("magnum-opus.txt");
}try {
DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null,
    outputStream);
System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
}finally {
outputStream.close();
```

Box API:

```
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, "id");
BoxFile.Info info = file.getInfo();

FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(info.getName());
file.download(stream);
stream.close();
```

App engine has outputstreams disabled. How can I solve this? What should i use for outputstream? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include code that shows what you've tried with Google.

Comment: App Engine only doesn't have _all_ output streams disabled, only classes such as `FileOutputStream` because there's no local filesystem accessible to applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what you're trying to write to Cloud Storage, so I will assume you already have some content that you want to write, in which case the Google Cloud Storage Client API ([javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/)) should give you what you're looking for.

In particular, [`GcsOutputChannel`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsOutputChannel).  This allows you to write to a specified location in GCS using a byte buffer or output stream.

e.g. ([from here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted#writing_an_object_to_a_gcs_file)):

```
GcsOutputChannel channel =
gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(channel));
out.writeObject(content);
out.close();
```

Comment: I wanted to download  the file into the cloud storage. But we decided to move away from app engine for now as it is not suitable for what we want to do. Thank you for your reply tx802